# Third Eye Activation

Tags: shiva, belief, meditation

Third eye activation is just so hair-raising to me.

1. How is it related to Hinduism?
2. How long does it take for third eye activation and does it cause any harm in any case?
3. Has anyone personally experienced? When does one realize the activation of the third eye, what are the indications?

Comment: Third Eye refers to Ajna chakra. Aspirant should have Sadhana to activate it. Aspirant should concentrate on **Trikuti** or place between eyebrows to activate it. Swami Sivananda wrote an excellent book on Kundalini Yoga describing [Science of Subtle Body and Chakras](http://www.dlshq.org/download/kundalini.htm) and their correlation to Lokas in Hinduism. (Replace .htm with .pdf to download it).

Comment: [Related but not duplicate] [About the mind's eye and the third eye in Hinduism](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8660/3500)

Answer (score 5):

The third-eye is related to the *Ajna Chakra*, intuition and awareness. These two answers might provide some insight:

> Q: What is the meaning of the opening of the third eye and what do I
>   feel when I experience this happening?
>
> Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: It is intuition, don’t think there is an eye
>   opening like this and something is popping up from your head. You get
>   a bump or a hole in your forehead, no! You know you close your eyes
>   still you feel some light; you may see or you may feel, it can be both
>   ways. If someone says I am going to open your third eye and this and
>   that, just don’t go into those things. I tell you, definitely not, it
>   is simply hoax because I have seen so many people claiming to open the
>   third eye and nothing happens really, people get a headache, an
>   incurable headaches many times and you get into problems. You know
>   many such cases come to us for repair, so if someone says I want to
>   open your third eye tell them, thank you very much, I am happy with
>   two eyes. The deeper you go in meditation your intuitive ability
>   develops.
>
> Q: Guruji, why is the opening of the third eye associated with the
>   destruction of desires?
>
> Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: You know the third eye is associated with
>   alertness and awareness. When you are alert, awake, more into
>   knowledge then naturally the energy has moved from the lowest chakra
>   to the highest. The lower things no more interest you. You know when
>   you are very alert and awake the sexual energy has transformed itself
>   into a different quality of consciousness. The sexual energy is when
>   the back portion of our brain, our head is activated. Alertness,
>   perception and awareness happen when the front portion of the brain is
>   activated; the pituitary and pineal glands are getting activated. In
>   the brain also they are on the opposite sides of each other. So it is
>   mythologically said when the third eye opens then the gross desires
>   simply evaporate, not that it is bad but they simply don’t make much
>   sense anymore. That is why the intellectuals and the highly spiritual
>   oriented practitioners always put something on the forehead, some
>   sandal wood paste because they are focusing; doing some yoga and
>   meditation so they put some sandal wood to cool the forehead, to cool
>   it a little bit.  When the frontal lobe of the brain becomes more
>   active, more alert, then thinking, intellectual work, creativity,
>   memory they are all enhanced because all of these things are in the
>   frontal lobe of the brain and sensory pleasures are all at the back of
>   the brain.

http://wisdomfromsrisriravishankar.blogspot.in/2011/04/deeper-you-go-in-meditation-your.html